# Virtual Euler Characteristic of a Curve in Brunella's paper

Tags: algebraic-geometry, foliations

I'm referring to

http://verbit.ru/MATH/Brunella/smf_bull_127_289-305.pdf

at pages 293 and 294. We are given two equations for a curve $C$ and a foliation $\mathcal{F}$ over a smooth algebraic surface $X$. The first one is when $C$ is invariant by $\mathcal{F}$:
$$
c_1(T\mathcal{F})\cdot C = \mathcal{X}(C)-Z(\mathcal{F},C)
$$
where $\mathcal{X}(C)$ is the virtual Euler characteristic of $C$ and $Z(\mathcal{F},C)$ is the sum of multiplicities of the singularities of $\mathcal{F}$ along $C$. The other equation is
$$
c_1(T\mathcal{F})\cdot C=C^2-tang(\mathcal{F},C)
$$

Now, proceeding to Lemma 1, we conclude that, if $C$ is $\mathcal{F}$-invariant, and supposing $Z(\mathcal{F},C)=0$, then we get
$$
c_1(T\mathcal{F})\cdot C = 2 - Z(\mathcal{F},C).
$$

Now, it's not pointed out anywhere, but this is possible if $\mathcal{X}(C)=2$. I could not see why this is true by myself, and would be pleased if someone could explain that to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

$C$ is rational, then $\chi(C)=2$.

For any projective curve in a surface, $\chi(C)=2 - 2p_a(C)$, $p_a(C)$ is the arithmetic genus of $C$. We have that $p_a(C) =0$ if, and only if, $C$ is a tree of smooth rational curves.

See BPV's [Compact Complex Surfaces](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-642-96754-2).

Comment: You're almost two years late! By the way the question was an exercise from your advisor :P

Comment: I know :p It just popped up when I installed the StackExchange APP

Comment: Nice to have you around, one more for me to pester with my newbie questions!

Comment: I hope you're not so newbe anymore. But we are forever newbies in some sense. "This never ends" (Soares, M.) :p

Comment: I am certainly more proficient in subjects not deeply related to the ones related to this question.
Nice quotation!